# How do I move a variable out of a closure?

Tags: closures, rust

I have a simple GTK app and I need to select a folder and pass it's path to a variable outside of the closure.

```
let mut path = "".to_owned();

button_open.connect_clicked(move |_| {
    let file_chooser = gtk::FileChooserDialog::new(
        "Open File", None, gtk::FileChooserAction::SelectFolder,
        [("Open", gtk::ResponseType::Ok), ("Cancel", gtk::ResponseType::Cancel)]);
    if file_chooser.run() == gtk::ResponseType::Ok as i32 {
        let filename = file_chooser.get_current_folder().unwrap();
    }

    file_chooser.destroy();
});
```

How do I assign `filename` to `path`? If I just write

```
path = filename;
```

I get this error:

```
src\main.rs:46:13: 46:28 error: cannot assign to captured outer variable in an `Fn` closure
src\main.rs:46             path = filename;
```

Comment: When your callback is executed, the outer fn will already have returned, so there's nothing left to assign to. You'll have to love the code using `filename` into the closure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do this for several reasons. [Here](http://gtk-rs.org/docs/gtk/signal/trait.ButtonSignals.html#tymethod.connect_clicked) is the definition of `connect_clicked()` method:

```
fn connect_clicked<F: Fn(Button) + 'static>(&self, f: F) -> u64
```

The closure which this method accepts is `Fn` and is bounded by `'static`. This means, first, that it can't modify its environment (that would be `FnMut`) and it also can't capture anything by reference (roughly what `'static` means). Therefore, there is *no* way for the closure to modify the `path` variable like you want.

Given that gtk-rs [enforces](https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk/blob/392202e23df34634f2be57bdf3a21d657336cfb8/src/rt.rs#L20-L32) that GTK can only be used from the main thread, and its widgets are not `Send`able, there is no way for the handler to access variables from another thread, so I'm not sure why these closures have `'static` bound, and I also see absolutely no reason why they are not `FnMut`. This seems to be an implementation defect.

Anyway, you can use `Rc<RefCell<..>>` to create a mutable piece of data:

```
let path: Rc<RefCell<Option<String>>> = Rc::new(RefCell::new(None));
let captured_path = path.clone();  // clone the Arc to use in closure
...
// inside the closure
*captured_path.borrow_mut() = Some(filename);
```

It is also possible to use `Arc<Mutex<..>>`, but I don't think it is necessary because gtk-rs protects against using GTK from any thread except the main one.

Comment: Aren't GUI frameworks usually single threaded? Still, the callback is definitely asynchronous, thus the 'static bound.

Comment: @Kha, by themselves they are single-threaded, but the main program is definitely not required to have only one thread, and the closure may close over variables from the main program easily. The most simple example would be running the event loop in a spawned thread: `thread::spawn(|| gtk::main())`. Then if the callback closes over the variables in the main thread, there may be problems. Most dire ones are mitigated by `'static` bound, but data races are still possible without synchronization which in `gtk-rs` is not enforced (no `Send` bound on closures).

Comment: By that logic, it sounds to me like _every_ closure would have to be `Send`. A closure to `Iterator::map` could just as well close over 'variables from the main program'. I think you only need `Send` on a closure if it will be executed on a different thread than the _caller_ (i.e. `thread::spawn` and friends).

Comment: @Kha, but that's what I'm talking about - the callback closure *will* be executed in another thread if `gtk::main()` is called in another thread. Iterator closure, on the other hand, can't be executed on another thread because putting a non-`Send` closure in it automatically makes it non-sendable so it can't even be passed to another thread. The problem with callbacks is that such "passing to another thread" with them is implicit.

Comment: Ah, I didn't get that you wanted to call `connect_clicked` from the main thread. But I think it would be highly unsafe in general if widgets could be controlled from any thread other than the event loop thread. Indeed, it seems like every method is guarded by https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk/blob/392202e23df34634f2be57bdf3a21d657336cfb8/src/rt.rs#L20-L32

Comment: Indeed, I was going to write just that. I've come up with an example program and found out that `gtk::main()` can only be called from the main thread. This does solve the problem - there is no way for the closure to run in non-main thread. So yes, it is safe.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If you don't mind, one question. Why do we have to clone `path` to `captured_path` and then use it in the closure, instead of just assigning `filename` to `path` directly?

Comment: @ehsisthatsweird, I've written it like this because, given that you want to assign something to that variable, you mean to use it after the closure. Therefore, `Rc` is used to share ownership, and `Rc`s must be cloned for that - otherwise `path` will be moved into the closure (remember the `move` keyword) and won't be accessible after the closure. If you don't intend to share the data (e.g. to keep some state between clicks), I think you can drop `Rc` outer layer entirely and just use `RefCell` directly.

Comment: How would you access the data inside the closure though? If I try to print it out, I get the error `the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `str``

Comment: @thouliha the error you're getting is not related to accessing variables in closures; it happens because you're trying to dereference a value of type `&str` in order to store it as a value of type `str`, which cannot be done because `str` is [unsized](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/unsized-types.html).

Comment: Thanks... how would I access the string?

Comment: @thouliha what exactly do you want to do with it? You can print it as easily as just `println!("{}",s)` where `s` is your captured variable. If you need to store it somewhere else (which would likely involve copying it), you can rely on autoref for method invocation targets and write `somewhere_else = s.to_string()`. It's hard to say anything more specific without concrete details of what you want to do. Also, comments here are not intended for long discussions; if you don't know how to solve some problem, you should better ask it as a separate question.

Comment: Running that just gives me the error: the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `std::cell::RefCell<std::option::Option<std::string::String>>` . I can't unwrap or use it unless I run *s.borrow_mut().unwrap(), in which case I get the error above.

Comment: You're getting this error because `{}` requires the formatted value to implement `Display`, but `Option<T>` does not implement it. As a quick fix, consider switching to `println!("{:?}", s)`, which uses `Debug`. And you cannot use `unwrap()` on a `&mut Option<T>` (and that's what `borrow_mut()` returns), because `unwrap()` needs `self` by value. Use `s.borrow().as_ref().unwrap()` to get a `&String` (`as_ref()` converts `&Option<T>` to `Option<&T>`, which is exactly what you need).